# Get the actual object rather than DBQuery in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm running this code in a mongodb console:

```
var participantsWithoutCategory = db.participant.find({eventId: ObjectId("536d5564e7b237df30b628cc"), category: {$exists: false}});
    var event = db.event.find({_id: ObjectId("536556c4eaa237df30b628cc")}); 

participantsWithoutCategory.forEach(function (entry) {
    var userId = new ObjectId("" + entry._id + "");
    var user = db.user.find( { _id: userId} );
    print("got user: " + user);
});
```

and the result of the prints is:

```
got user: DBQuery: Oc5mjdKkhyDb3r6rhnzw.user -> { "_id" : ObjectId("536d8586ebb237df30b62bcb") }
```

so I'm just wondering how to get the actual object rather than a pointer to it?

if I try to get any of its properties such as user.dob I get a null :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that's how mongo says that the query had no results... I've fixed it by using the right property of the object and not the _id but that's beyond the point.

The interesting thing here is that mongo gives back the DBQuery when find() returns nothing.

Comment: You could have null back if you use findOne